# Manually move text up html

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm very new to HTML and just started making my first website. I was just wondering how one would do could move text through HTML not CSS, they say a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: http://s28.postimg.org/8jvt54zy5/Screen_Shot_2014_09_08_at_3_45_31_PM.png]

So my goal is to get the text saying 'Typography' into the first red box, and the rest into the red box below it.

Is there a way to do this with only HTML, or should I write some funky CSS to deal with that?

Comment: I'd say CSS is a good idea.

Comment: It would help if you posted the HTML you're working with, although the answer is to put the text inside the respective HTML elements regardless.  If you post HTML i can pay answer showing you.

Comment: HTML and CSS go hand in hand, there's no real reason to avoid using CSS in this situation. Think of HTML as the content in the page, and CSS as how the page shows that information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CSS is necessary because the default styling in every major browser does exactly what you've pictured. If elements are `inline-block`, they align toward the bottom of the preceding `img`, `div`, or other element. (Technically, the preceding element will also align to the bottom of the next element if the next element is taller. So really, all shorter elements align to the bottom of the tallest element if they're in a row.) To  align them to the top, you have to set a `vertical-align` property to the the preceding `img` or `div`.

[Here's a very simple example of this.](http://jsfiddle.net/d006nctv/)

However, you can't get a browser to add more text (or any other content, for that matter) in your second red square without wrapping what you have in a `div` or other element.

[Thus we do this.](http://jsfiddle.net/d006nctv/1/)

Here are some [additional examples](http://jsfiddle.net/toyatkch/) of how inline-block elements behave next to one another with and without `vertical-align` set.

Other style adjustments, like separating the `p` further from the `h1`, can be made with CSS's `margin` or `padding` rules.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the best way possible i found out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style>
#RedBoxOneText{font-size:30px; margin:45px 280px; color:red; position:absolute;}
#RedBoxTwoText{font-size:18px; margin:130px 280px; color:blue; position:absolute; width:500px;}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<div id="RedBoxOneText">Typography</div>
<div id="RedBoxTwoText">Typography text box with random words words words words words words words words words</div>

<img src="http://s28.postimg.org/8jvt54zy5/Screen_Shot_2014_09_08_at_3_45_31_PM.png">


</body>
```

the "Position:absolute;" ensures the specified div is floating above everything in a simple way

the "Margin:45px 280px;" makes the text float in the coordinates given

the "width:500px;" for the RED BOX TWO makes a invisible border wrapped around the text, making it larger will make the text fly off the image in a straight line depending on how many pixels you set it too

the "font-Size:28px;" makes the text size bigger or smaller depending on the value you put there

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Needlessly setting `position: absolute` isn't a good idea, especially when there are CSS rules specifically designed to fix OP's problem.

Comment: Well it gets the job done. Its short, I made it easy to understand, and given a code example above. If you changed the code to your specified needs it'd still turn out the same way it is displayed. no matter how professional or poor you code your page, it still turns out the way you want it to be. And if it doesn't work, make some changes a bit

Comment: Using `position: absolute` where it doesn't belong makes things very hard to maintain very quickly. If OP takes learning web development seriously at all, teaching him antipatterns to temporarily fix his problem does him far more harm than good.

Comment: If he ever does take things seriously he can learn alot from youtube videos. i did a simple thing for him. As he stated "I'm very new to HTML and just started making my first website" notice the "Very New" part in the sentence. Dont give someone something difficult to understand. For example, I bet he has no idea what "you have to set a vertical-align property to the the preceding img or div" means, Like what code does he type? And how does he type it?. like "Create a style sheet and link it to the html" He probably knows that but HOW does he do it? you need more info, he is VERY NEW to html

Comment: In my original, unedited answer I liked to two JSFiddles explaining *exactly* what code to write. I'm not really one for arguing on the Internet, but this is HTML/CSS 101. It's not any more difficult than what you wrote, but it's *correct*. `absolute` positioning is unmaintainable because the more it's used the more elements are taken out of the flow of the document, forcing you to keep using it. Setting scores of elements to `absolute` because you don't know better is counterproductive on a static page [continued]

Comment: [cont], significantly (probably orders of magnitude) more tedious on a responsive page, and virtually impossible on a dynamic page. So I really don't think it's a good idea to plant in someone's head. I know because I've been there, debugging poorly-positioned elements for hours upon hours when I first started out several years ago. The whole time I should have just learned it the right way from the get-go because it would have saved me an enormous amount of time. So I really, strongly disagree with you.

Comment: so is the guy supposed to change the black background to his image (Example: "background-Image:url(http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z45h.png);") or what O_o

Comment: `img` and `div` (and every other element) have the same inline-block behavior, so yes.

Comment: Nevermind about this whole thing; My work is junk, Doing what you said to your code does not make the text FLOAT over the image like he wants, I am very Tired, i have dumb school in twelve hours, and my room smells like valentina salsa...

Comment: ...He doesn't want it to float over the image he posted. He's not making a website about "filler text." The image was a reference for what he's trying to achieve. He wants to position one element (either an `img` or a `div`, presumably) to the left of two pieces of text that are stacked on top of each other.

Comment:  oh.. lol, I must of got confused with another problem I'm dealing with... He could do " </br> " but I don't think it'd turn out right